# Symfony2 Option values on ChoiceList

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to set custom values for Select Options using Form types and 'choice_list'.

Type:

```
   ->add('status', 'choice', array(
      'constraints' => array(
       new Assert\NotBlank(array('message' => 'Required field missing: status'))
      ),
      'error_bubbling' => true,
      'choice_list' => new StatusChoiceList()
```

StatusChoiceList file:

```
class StatusChoiceList extends LazyChoiceList
{
    /**
     * Loads the choice list
     *
     * Should be implemented by child classes.
     *
     * @return ChoiceListInterface The loaded choice list
     */
    protected function loadChoiceList()
    {
        $array = array(
            'Preview' => 'Preview',
            'Hidden'  => 'Hidden',
            'Live'    => 'Live'
        );
        $choices = new ChoiceList($array, $array);

        return $choices;
    }
}
```

the select tag have a wrong values 0,1,2 and a good labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ChoiceList](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php) class used for choices of arbitrary data types. In your case you should use [SimpleChoiceList](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/SimpleChoiceList.php) instead. First parameter is an array with choices as keys and labels as values.

```
protected function loadChoiceList()
{
    $array = array(
        'Preview' => 'Preview',
        'Hidden'  => 'Hidden',
        'Live'    => 'Live'
    );
    $choices = new SimpleChoiceList($array);

    return $choices;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of `SimpleChoiceList` and it was exactly what I was looking for.